# PHP: Using too many nested loops, looking for a more efficient solution

Tags: php, performance, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

My script is centred around the array `$givenNumbers` with a random amount of random numbers from 1-1000:

```
$givenNumbers = [383, 886, 777, 84, 327, 336, 505, 846, 729, 313, 857, 124, 895, 582, 545, 814, 367, 434, 364, 43, 750, 87, 808, 276, 178, 788, 584, 403, 651, 754, 399, 932, 60, 676, 368, 739, 12, 226, 586, 94, 539, 654, 999, 5, 24];
```

The array is sorted and all repetitions of elements are removed:

```
 $givenNumbers = array_unique($givenNumbers);
 sort($givenNumbers);
```

I then declare the variable `$amount` which is the amount of elements in `$givenNumbers`;

```
$amount = count($givenNumbers);
```

I now store all possible slices of the array in the array `$slices` by using loops:

```
$slices = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < $amount; $j++) {
            array_push($slices, array_slice($givenNumbers, $i, $j));
        }
    }
```

Having stored all slices in `$slices` I want to find all possible combinations of ten slices which, if merged together, will contain all elements of `$givenNumbers` without any element appearing twice or more.

I tried to do this by looping through the keys of `slices`:

```
$combinations[]
for($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
        for($j = $i+1; $j < $amount; $j++) {   
            for($k = $j+1; $k < $amount; $k++) {
                for($l = $k+1; $l < $amount; $l++) {
                    for($m = $l+1; $m < $amount; $m++) {
                        for($n = $m+1; $n < $amount; $n++) {   
                            for($o = $n+1; $o < $amount; $o++) {
                                for($p = $o+1; $p < $amount; $p++) {
                                    for($q = $p+1; $q < $amount; $q++) {
                                        for($r = $q+1; $r < $amount; $r++) {

                                            $combStorer = [];
                                            $placeholder = array_merge($slices[$i], $slices[$j], $slices[$k], $slices[$l], $slices[$m], $slices[$n], $slices[$o], $slices[$p], $slices[$q], $slices[$r]);
                                            $placeholder = array_unique($placeholder);
                                            if (count($placeholder) == $amount) {
                                                    array_push($placeholder, $slices[$i], $slices[$j], $slices[$k], $slices[$l], $slices[$m], $slices[$n], $slices[$o], $slices[$p], $slices[$q], $slices[$r]);
                                                    foreach ($placeholder as $comb) {
                                                    $combStorer[] = $comb;
                                                }
                                                $combinations[] = $combStorer;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This should basically find all combinations of ten arrays in `slices` which meet my requirement and store them in the form of a multidimensional array in `$combinations`.

However, when I open my live preview, I get a fatal error, since the maximum execution of 30 seconds has been exceeded.

Several users have brought to my attention that this method is too convoluted and that there is definitely a better solution.

Could anyone suggest a more efficient solution?

Comment: I don't even want to know what's the purpose of all this.

Comment: What makes you say the loop must be infinite? The inner loop will run a number of times equal to `$amount` to the power of 10. Even if `$amount` is just 2, that is 1024 times. If `$amount` is 3, it will run 59,049 times. For bigger values this will increase vastly. So it is hardly surprising that your script is timing out, and not surprising at all that removing a couple of the loops (so it only runts n^8 times instead of n^10) makes a huge difference. You need to find a more efficient way of doing whatever it is that you are trying.

Comment: It can happen that loop is not infinite, but just long enough to be greater than 30 seconds. Decrease `$amount` and check.

Comment: Provide the `$amount` value. Also, try to increase the execution time.

Comment: I tested (just for fun) with $amount=15 and got `91011121314101112131411121314...` (many more) when I echo `$r`.

Comment: whats the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not infinite, it's just a *very* *very* large number of iterations, basically:

```
(amount ^ 10) / 2
```

That ramps up extremely quickly, e.g, for increasing values for `amount`:

```
$ time php index.php 5

real    0m0.067s
user    0m0.043s
sys     0m0.023s
$ time php index.php 10

real    0m0.061s
user    0m0.046s
sys     0m0.014s
$ time php index.php 15

real    0m0.117s
user    0m0.096s
sys     0m0.012s
$ time php index.php 20

real    0m0.546s
user    0m0.506s
sys     0m0.030s
$ time php index.php 25

real    0m3.245s
user    0m3.204s
sys     0m0.032s
$ time php index.php 30

real    0m24.624s
user    0m24.129s
sys     0m0.032s
$ time php index.php 35

real    1m55.215s
user    1m54.532s
sys     0m0.029s
```